# Koin - single instance per parameter value

Tags: koin

I have a module:

```
single{ (name: String) -> Person(name) }
```

When I do:

```
val alice: Person by inject {parametersOf("Alice")}
val bob: Person by inject {parametersOf("Bob")}
```

I get 2 instances of Alice. All parameters other than the first are ignored.

Is there a simple way to make Koin treat those 2 as different? Parameters are not known in advance, so I can't use named properties. `factory` won't do either, I need to reuse instances with same parameter sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing directly in Koin, but it's easy enough to make something that works this way.

1) a class that does create-if-not-present:

```
class DistinctFactory<K, V>(private val newInstance: (K) -> V) {
    private val _locker = Any()
    private val mRepo: HashMap<K, V> = HashMap()

    operator fun get(id: K): V {
        return mRepo[id] ?: run {
            synchronized(_locker) {
                mRepo[id] ?: run {
                    newInstance(id).also {
                        mRepo[id] = it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Koin single of DistinctFactory:

```
single { DistinctFactory<String, Person> { Person(it) } }
```

3) Koin factory that uses the previous single:

```
factory { (name: String) -> get<DistinctFactory<String, Person>>()[name] }
```

test:

```
val alice: Person by inject {parametersOf("Alice")}
val bob: Person by inject {parametersOf("Bob")}
val aliceAgain: Person by inject {parametersOf("Alice")}

alice === aliceAgain
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module {

    val personCache = HashMap<Int, Person>()

    factory { parameters ->
        val hash = parameters.values.hashCode()
        personCache.getOrPut(hash) {
            Person(parameters.get())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work sometimes because 1) hash is meant to not be unique. 2)`getOrPut` is not atomic so you're risking duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the garbage colleciton work with @agent-l solution, make sure to use WeakReference as well.

```
class DistinctFactory<K, V>(private val newInstance: (K) -> V) {
    private val _locker = Any()
    private val mRepo: HashMap<K, WeakReference<V>> = HashMap()

    operator fun get(id: K): V {
        return mRepo[id]?.get() ?: run {
            synchronized(_locker) {
                mRepo[id]?.get() ?: run {
                    newInstance(id).also {
                        mRepo[id] = WeakReference(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```